# regex to remove all text before a character

Tags: regex

Is there an easy way to remove all chars before a "_"? For example, change `3.04_somename.jpg` to `somename.jpg`.

Any suggestions for where to learn to write regex would be great too. Most places I check are hard to learn from.

Comment: In which language ? there are a few varieties of Regex you see.

Comment: This is a classic http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Comment: first, it is not hard. and, you need to point out in which situation your problem is.

Comment: @RussC: In this case, the language isn't all that relevant because that kind of regex is so basic (and doesn't need any of those newfangled non-regular regex extensions), it'll work in more or less any regex engine, even POSIX BREs. Of course, the OP still needs to know how to apply the regex to his string, so you're still right, of course.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

```
^[^_]*_
```

will match all text up to the first underscore. Replace that with the empty string.

For example, in C#:

```
resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, 
    @"^   # Match start of string
    [^_]* # Match 0 or more characters except underscore
    _     # Match the underscore", "", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
```

For learning regexes, take a look at http://www.regular-expressions.info

Comment: any idea how to do this in javascript?

Comment: The regex is exactly the same; the site I linked to contains all the info on how to do a regex replace in JavaScript.

Comment: @Lukasz - in JavaScript you do:
var result = '3.04_somename.jpg'.replace(/^[^_]*_/, '');

Comment: How can I extend this RegEx to go all the way till the last occurance of the '_'?

Comment: @ChanandlerBong: You would use a different regex for that, not extend the current one. Something like `^.*_` would be the simplest way.

Answer (score 7):

The regular expression:

```
^[^_]*_(.*)$
```

Then get the part between parenthesis.
In perl:

```
my var = "3.04_somename.jpg";
$var =~ m/^[^_]*_(.*)$/;
my fileName = $1;
```

In Java:

```
String var = "3.04_somename.jpg";
String fileName = "";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[^_]*_(.*)$");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(var);
if (matcher.matches()) {
    fileName = matcher.group(1);
}
```

...

Answer (score 4):

no need to do a replacement. the regex will give you what u wanted directly:

```
"(?<=_)[^_]*\.jpg"
```

tested with grep:

```
 echo "3.04_somename.jpg"|grep -oP "(?<=_)[^_]*\.jpg"
somename.jpg
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for, thanks! I'll give these suggestions a try. Working with Perl regex here.

Answer (score 3):

Variant of Tim's one, good only on some implementations of Regex: `^.*?_`

```
var subjectString = "3.04_somename.jpg";
var resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString,
    @"^   # Match start of string
    .*?   # Lazily match any character, trying to stop when the next condition becomes true
    _     # Match the underscore", "", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
```

Answer (score 2):

In Javascript I would use `/.*_/`, meaning: match everything until _ (including)

Example:

```
console.log( 'hello_world'.replace(/.*_/,'') ) // 'world'
```

Answer (score 1):

For Notepad++ users who are getting all but one line's results deleted, try this:

```
^.*_
```

Check the box for "Wrap around"
Uncheck the box for "matches newline"
Click "Replace All"

Source: https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/notepad-plus-find-and-replace-text/

Answer (score 0):

I learned all my Regex from this website: http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/regex.htm.
Google on 'Regex tutorials' and you'll find loads of helful articles.

```
String regex = "[a-zA-Z]*\.jpg";
System.out.println ("somthing.jpg".matches (regex));
```

returns true.

Comment: You'll want to escape the dot :)

Answer (score 0):

If you cast your url as [System.Uri], the localPath field gives you what you want:

```
$link_url = "https://www.subdomain.domain.com/files
$local_path= [System.Uri]::new($link_url)
```

Will yield $local_path = /files