# Use Regex re.sub to remove everything before and including a specified word

Tags: python, regex

I've got a string, which looks like "Blah blah blah, Updated: Aug. 23, 2012", from which I want to use Regex to extract just the date `Aug. 23, 2012`. I found an article in the stacks which has something similar: [regex to remove all text before a character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7793950/regex-to-remove-all-text-before-a-character), but that's not working either when I tried

```
date_div = "Blah blah blah, Updated: Aug. 23, 2012"
extracted_date = re.sub('^[^Updated]*',"", date_div)
```

How can I remove everything up to and including Updated, so that only `Aug. 23, 2012`is left over?

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In this case, you can do it withot regex, e.g:

```py
>>> date_div = "Blah blah blah, Updated: Aug. 23, 2012"
>>> date_div.split('Updated: ')
['Blah blah blah, ', 'Aug. 23, 2012']
>>> date_div.split('Updated: ')[-1]
'Aug. 23, 2012'
```

Answer (score 7):

With a regex, you may use two regexps depending on the occurrence of the word:

```
# Remove all up to the first occurrence of the word including it (non-greedy):
^.*?word
# Remove all up to the last occurrence of the word including it (greedy):
^.*word
```

See the [non-greedy regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/c5NbCn/1) and a [greedy regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/c5NbCn/2).

The `^` matches the start of string position, `.*?` matches any 0+ chars (mind the use of `re.DOTALL` flag so that `.` could match newlines) as *few* as possible (`.*` matches as *many* as possible) and then `word` matches and consumes (i.e. adds to the match and advances the regex index) the word.

Note the use of `re.escape(up_to_word)`: if your `up_to_word` does not consist of sole alphanumeric and underscore chars, it is safer to use `re.escape` so that special chars like `(`, `[`, `?`, etc. could not prevent the regex from finding  a valid match.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/2UgAqj):

```
import re

date_div = "Blah blah\nblah, Updated: Aug. 23, 2012 Blah blah Updated: Feb. 13, 2019"

up_to_word = "Updated:"
rx_to_first = r'^.*?{}'.format(re.escape(up_to_word))
rx_to_last = r'^.*{}'.format(re.escape(up_to_word))

print("Remove all up to the first occurrence of the word including it:")
print(re.sub(rx_to_first, '', date_div, flags=re.DOTALL).strip())
print("Remove all up to the last occurrence of the word including it:")
print(re.sub(rx_to_last, '', date_div, flags=re.DOTALL).strip())
```

Output:

```
Remove all up to the first occurrence of the word including it:
Aug. 23, 2012 Blah blah Updated: Feb. 13, 2019
Remove all up to the last occurrence of the word including it:
Feb. 13, 2019
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use Lookahead:

```
import re
date_div = "Blah blah blah, Updated: Aug. 23, 2012"
extracted_date = re.sub('^(.*)(?=Updated)',"", date_div)
print extracted_date
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Updated: Aug. 23, 2012
```

**EDIT**
If MattDMo's comment below is correct and you want to remove the "Update: " as well you can do:

```
extracted_date = re.sub('^(.*Updated: )',"", date_div)
```

Comment: I think OP wants to remove `Updated: ` as well