# Python Regex Function

Tags: python, regex

I would like to remove all the unnecessary characters (in bold) before the 1st entry in a python list. I am trying to use regex to make it happen, please review my code?

Edit : I would like to remove all characters before and including the word safe.

> ['**xian/gps_201610010000644016240301624032416162641013323634045015307
>   0ustar 
>   bigdata_safebigdata_safe**a01b8439e1e42ffcd286241b04d9b1b5,f11440a64a0f084fe346a398c62aa9ad,1475277482,108.92466,34.27657',
>   'a01b8439e1e42ffcd286241b04d9b1b5,f11440a64a0f084fe346a398c62aa9ad,1475277488,108.92527,34.27658',
>   'a01b8439e1e42ffcd286241b04d9b1b5,f11440a64a0f084fe346a398c62aa9ad,1475277506,108.9276,34.27659',
>   'a01b8439e1e42ffcd286241b04d9b1b5,f11440a64a0f084fe346a398c62aa9ad,1475277476,108.92399,34.27655',
>   'a01b8439e1e42ffcd286241b04d9b1b5,f11440a64a0f084fe346a398c62aa9ad,1475277515,108.9291,34.2766']

```
def removePunctuation(text):
    text = re.sub(r"\x00+",'',text) 
    test = re.sub(r'.*a01', '',text)
    return text
```

Comment: And what is the rule for the bold text? See https://regex101.com/r/rBLzxD/1 for the actual example.

Comment: `return re.sub(r'^.*?(a01)', r'\1', text)`? This will work if all the junk chars appear at the start of the string and the real data starts with `a01`.

Comment: Your problem is that `.*` is greedy and will match everything until the last occurence of `a01`  if you make it non-greedy with `.*?` as in the demo of Jan it should work

Comment: there is no rule for the bold text. I just want to remove those unnecessary characters. what would the resultant code look like?

Comment: You cannot solve a programming task without requirements. If you have no rules for that, just leave as is, it will be better than corrupting it further.

Comment: sorry last question. instead of being specific like what @Wiktor mentioned. Can I just remove all characters before and including the word safe?

Comment: You can. Have you tried that already? Please add the requirement to the *question*

Comment: return re.sub(r'^.*?(a01)', r'\1', text)...I want to do it in terms of regex

Comment: It is my code suggestion and it does not "remove all characters before and including the word safe"

Comment: Duplicate of [Use Regex re.sub to remove everything before and including a specified word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25045373/use-regex-re-sub-to-remove-everything-before-and-including-a-specified-word).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

OP: *there is no rule for the bold text.*, assuming the corrupt text will end with `safe`:

```
import re

def removePunctuation(text):
    for elem in text:
        if elem.startswith('a01'):
            print(elem)
        else:
            elem = elem.rpartition('safe')[2]
            print(elem)

test_list = ['xian/gps_201610010000644016240301624032416162641013323634045015307 0ustar bigdata_safebigdata_safea01b8439e1e42ffcd286241b04d9b1b5,f11440a64a0f084fe346a398c62aa9ad,1475277482,108.92466,34.27657',
             'a01b8439e1e42ffcd286241b04d9b1b5,f11440a64a0f084fe346a398c62aa9ad,1475277488,108.92527,34.27658',
             'a01b8439e1e42ffcd286241b04d9b1b5,f11440a64a0f084fe346a398c62aa9ad,1475277506,108.9276,34.27659',
             'a01b8439e1e42ffcd286241b04d9b1b5,f11440a64a0f084fe346a398c62aa9ad,1475277476,108.92399,34.27655',
             'a01b8439e1e42ffcd286241b04d9b1b5,f11440a64a0f084fe346a398c62aa9ad,1475277515,108.9291,34.2766']



removePunctuation(test_list)
```

OUTPUT:

```
a01b8439e1e42ffcd286241b04d9b1b5,f11440a64a0f084fe346a398c62aa9ad,1475277482,108.92466,34.27657
a01b8439e1e42ffcd286241b04d9b1b5,f11440a64a0f084fe346a398c62aa9ad,1475277488,108.92527,34.27658
a01b8439e1e42ffcd286241b04d9b1b5,f11440a64a0f084fe346a398c62aa9ad,1475277506,108.9276,34.27659
a01b8439e1e42ffcd286241b04d9b1b5,f11440a64a0f084fe346a398c62aa9ad,1475277476,108.92399,34.27655
a01b8439e1e42ffcd286241b04d9b1b5,f11440a64a0f084fe346a398c62aa9ad,1475277515,108.9291,34.2766
```