# find ALL signs(characters, whitespaces, digits etc.) before regex

Tags: regex, perl

I want to find(to remove this with perl, but this is not the question) all characters, digits, whitespaces before a special regex.

Example:

```
this is my test
foo ... == < foo
something else

myregex
 all other
```

So I want to find

```
this is my test
foo ... == < foo
something else
```

its ok when

```
myregex
```

is also "highlighted".

I found some other post [regex to remove all text before a character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7793950/regex-to-remove-all-text-before-a-character), but this does not realy match my problem...

Comment: `s/.*(?=myregex)//;`

Comment: see https://regex101.com/r/yU1rE3/1

Comment: perfect answers :) thanks

Answer (score -1):

The question is worded very badly. As I understand it, you want to remove everything before the part that matches your regular expression.

If that's the case, this might help: `s/.*(<REGEX>)/\1/g`
This matches all the characters before your regex (`.*`) and then matches your regex and creates a group. Once the matching is complete, it replaces all the matched section with the contents of the group alone (`\1`).