# Swagger UI displaying the asp.net webapi parameter name with dot notation

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I have configured Swagger for my asp.net webapi which is similar to one shown below

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("search")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get([FromUri]SearchCriteria searchCriteria)
```

When i see the swagger documentation for the webapi , the parameter is displaying as

searchCriteria.sortField
searchCriteria.sortDirection
and so on... being the sortField, sortDirection are properties of SearchCriteria

[image]

How to get the parameter names without the object.propertyname format?

Can anyone help how to fix this?
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an `OperationFilter` I once used to remove the class name from query parameters.

```
public class ParameterFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    private const string Pattern = @"^ # Match start of string
                .*? # Lazily match any character, trying to stop when the next condition becomes true
                \.  # Match the dot";
    public void Apply(Operation operation, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, ApiDescription apiDescription)
    {
        if (operation.parameters == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        foreach (var parameter in operation.parameters
            .Where(x => x.@in == "query" && x.name.Contains(".")))
        {
            parameter.name = Regex.Replace(
                parameter.name,
                Pattern, 
                string.Empty, 
                RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
        }
    }
}
```

Add it to you `SwaggerConfig` like this:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
    .EnableSwagger(c =>
        {
            // other settings omitted
            c.OperationFilter<ParameterFilter>();    
        });
```

BTW: The regex is inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/7794128/502395

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using Swashbuckle.

Look at `DocumentFilters` and `OperationFilters`. You can extend Swashbuckle to intervene at the document or operation level to modify the output.

Read through the [Swashbuckle documentation](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle), it is fairly straight forward to implement either of these two interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass parameter `Name = ""` to the `FormUri` attribute Swashbuckle generates parameter names in unqualified form e.g. `sortField` instead of `searchCriteria.sortField`.

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get([FromUri(Name = "")]SearchCriteria searchCriteria)
```