# Seperate inputs for fields instead of a single body

Tags: swashbuckle

Is it possible to have seperate textboxes for request fields in Swagger UI instead of a single Body textarea for the whole model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the `[FromUri]` attribute to the parameter. That might, however, result in something you do not like or want as presented in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37705821/swagger-ui-displaying-the-asp-net-webapi-parameter-name-with-dot-notation) but that can be circumvented by the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37714634/502395) I gave.